# How can I copy all files which starts with a letter and ends with another to a specific folder?

Tags: command-line, files

I’m using Ubuntu-Linux terminal. I want to move from one directory to another the files that begin with the letter “T” and end with “-AN”. Besides, only “.txt” files. I want to do it in the same command. Any suggestions?

Comment: [edit] your question wit the exact command you used in terminal

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. While I am not opposed to helping people learn things, it's generally better to *guide* someone to a solution rather than simply provide one 

Comment: If a filename ends with `AN`, it cannot end with `.txt`. My conclusion: no files to move, homework done...

Comment: `*` will match any number of characters ... So `cp dir1/T*-AN.txt dir2/` :-)

Comment: @mook765 :-D ... I guess OP meant the part of the filename before the `.txt` part

Comment: @Raffa OP should not let us guess what is meant, a question has to be clear.

Comment: @mook765 Sure, can't argue with that :-)

Answer (score 3):

**First**, a **file name** actually refers to everything(*including the file extension*) ... So you might want to pay attention to that when asking/explaining in the future.

**Second**, it appears that you want to match all files that start with the character `T`(*case matters here*) and followed by zero or more characters then followed by `-AN.txt`(*case matters here as well*) ... For that you can make use of what is called *shell globbing*(*AKA wildcard matching*) using the `*`(*asterisk or star*) character which matches zero or more of any character.

**Third**, you use the word (*copy*) in the title and the word (*move*) in the body of your question interchangeably ... but they are **not** the same ... So to copy you use `cp` like so:

```
cp -- dir1/T*-AN.txt dir2/
```

and to move, you use `mv` like so:

```
mv -- dir1/T*-AN.txt dir2/
```

Where `dir1/` is the source directory and `dir2/` is the destination directory.